# Exit processes launched from cmd with cmd exit

Tags: process, cmd

I wrote a script that launches a cmd window. Cmd window further launches several processes. What I want is that on closing the cmd window manually or using exit command, all processes launched via cmd also get killed.

Comment: Closing the window with the red X will kill some processes and not others - it depends on the processes and how they were launched. For example `start calc` will start the calculator and killing the cmd window with the red X will not kill the calculator and it can't be scripted within the same batch file.  Further details would be needed to give you a workaround.

Comment: `taskkilll /t` is best there is. Windows has job objects but I know of no command line interface.

Comment: show us what you have done so far, then someone might help you. Also see this: [How to ask good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not possible to change how the exit command works. What you could do is make your own custom start and exit commands by having something like this:

Start Command Batch File: (context would be `start2 program.exe`)

```
start "" "%1"
if exist onExit.txt echo %1>> onExit.txt
if not exist onExit.txt echo %1> onExit.txt
```

**Save that as start2.bat**

Exit command BatchFile: (context would just be `Exit2`)

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (onExit.txt) do  (taskkill /f /im "%%A"
exit
```

**Save that as Exit2.bat**

*What those scripts do is keep track of each program you start with the custom command `start2` and then `taskkill` them on your custom exit. You could have these files in the same directory of the batch file, or you could even have your batch file create these files with `echo file contents> file.bat` and `echo more file contents>> file.bat`. This is the best you could probably do without placing the actual cmd Executable in system32, which I would certainly not recommend since many other programs use it. Hope this helps*